# Need some explaination regarding why "1"- -"1" expression returns 2?

Tags: javascript, string, math, numbers

Going through an online test, i found this weird expression where

```
"1"- -"1" = 2
```

i understand `-"1"` will be converted to number, but the other `"1"-` is getting converted too?

Comment: yes, it is, because you can't "subtract" strings

Comment: learn about duck typing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't subtract strings - so they are converted to numbers:

```
1 - -1
```

Two minuses make a plus:

```
1 + 1
```

And if you can prove it, that is equal to 2:

```
1 + 1 = 2
```

```js
console.log("1" - - "1");
```